# CS50 Web - Project 4 Network

Tags: javascript, python, cs50

I am currently working on the CS50 Web Project 4 - Network. The task is to design a twitter-like Network. Currently, I am stuck at the Like-Function.

I have a like-button and a counter of the likes. When I click the like-button, the counter on the page says "undefined". But when I reload the page, everything is fine and the like-count shows the right number of likes and also the like button has changed to an unlike button. Does anyone have an idea what the issues? I am stuck for days now and cannot figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code:

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def like(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

    if request.method == "PUT":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        if data.get("like"):
            Likes.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
            post.likes = Likes.objects.filter(post=post).count()
        else:
            Likes.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post).delete()
            post.likes = Likes.objects.filter(post=post).count()
        post.save()
        return HttpResponse("done")
```

java.js

```
function like(id) {
    fetch(`/like/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            like: true
        })
    })
    .then(post => {
        document.querySelector(`#like_count${id}`).innerHTML = post.likes;
    });
}

function unlike(id) {
    fetch(`/like/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            like: false
        })
    })
    .then(post => {
        document.querySelector(`#like_count${id}`).innerHTML = post.likes;
    });
}
```

and on my html:

```
<div id="like_count{{post.id}}">Likes: {{ post.likes }}</div>

{% if liked %}
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="unlike_button{{post.id}}" onclick="unlike('{{ post.id }}')">Unlike</button>

{% else %}
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="like_button{{post.id}}" onclick="like('{{ post.id }}')">Like</button>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your view only ever returns `"done"`, not an object that would have a `likes` attribute.
   You may want something like `return JSONResponse({"likes": post.likes})` instead.
2. The value `fetch()` returns is a Response. (You're trying to access `likes` on it.) You'll need to await on `res.json()` to decode a JSON response into an object. (While at it, we can remove a bit of repetition in the code.)

```
function likeOrUnlike(id, like) {
  fetch(`/like/${id}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: JSON.stringify({ like: !!like }),
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((post) => {
      document.querySelector(`#like_count${id}`).innerHTML = post.likes;
    });
}

function like(id) {
  likeOrUnlike(id, true);
}

function unlike(id) {
  likeOrUnlike(id, false);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! the like-count now works perfectly. but the like button is still only changing when i refresh the page. i check if the post is liked or not in my index view. how can i refresh this information via the javascript-code?

Comment: It might be easier to have both the like button and the unlike button in your page source, but only show one depending on whether the thing is liked or not (using e.g. `style="display:none"`). Then it'd be easy to flip the visibilities in the JavaScript code.

Comment: thanks a lot, again! i had to restructure a few things, but now i have added an if-statement to my java script to change the style/visibility depending on the value